# custom RequestHandler in solr

Tags: solr, requesthandler

I have written a custom request handler in solr and added following line in solrconfig.xml:
requestHandler name="/xyz" class="" enable="${enable_xyz:true}"/
But still I cannot see its working.

Through logs I checked that a http GET request has been made to this requestHandler. Also the response send by it looks ok to me:
`<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">0</int></lst>`[\n]"

But still it is not doing the required task.

Can someone point me what could go wrong.

Comment: How you try to access this requestHandler? Could you attach solrconfig.xml? Also, show us, the code of this requestHandler

Comment: @Mysterion, I cannot share the code. Thats why I just wanted to ask what could be the possible fault.
My biggest doubt is that, i cannot see any error in logs, then why handler code is not picked?

Comment: It looks like your handler was requested, it looks like a problem is inside your code. Take a look here - https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRequestHandler